# SQL/LINQ C# Timeout No Matter What

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

In order to send emails out, we look up some email credentials for our "botmail". Now this code worked just fine not too long ago, however after moving it from our server, it has constant SQL timeout exceptions. I've already tried changing the timeout for the connection string itself and I've tried changing the CommandTimeout within OnCreated (both in our DataContext class for the ctx variable). No matter what I change, I constantly get the same exception. Is there something I'm missing here?

Code:

```
if (Enumerable.Any(from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select c))
{
    serverHostname = (from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select c.Hostname).First();
    serverUsername = (from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select c.UserName).First();
    serverPassword = (from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select c.Password).First();
    mailFrom = (from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select c.Mail_From).First();
}
```

Comment: Why are you making individual queries afor each value instead of getting them all at once? Also if that simple command is causing a timeout, I suspect something is very wrong with your sql server.

Comment: I argee with  dman2306. If you indeed set large timeout on your DbContext, more likely you have wrong connection string and specified DB server is not available in your new programm environment.

Comment: My eyes bleeding. I've written it in normal way. It probably won't help you with question you asked, but definitely will help you with LINQ. [DotnetfiddleLink](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPGTrj)

Comment: When you moved from your server, did you maybe forget to apply indexes?

Comment: @NDJ Honestly, I was just thrown onto this project from the last guy, so I can't quite say whether we have or haven't. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Володин Андрей Would that still be the case even if the rest of the program is capable of communicating with the database?

Comment: Yes, It can. If you use different connection strings in your programm

Comment: Use sql profiler. Is the command getting to the sql server? If so, analyze the query plan of the query to see what's going on. If it doesn't get to the server it sounds like a networking error or connection string problem.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize.

At first, the problem is more likely in a connection string. When you move programm in another place, you DB server is no longer available in new environment. Programm try to open connection, wait for server responce and throw timeout exception.
It is unlikely that such SQL queries can be made for a long time, because it's search for a first row in a table. And even if table have many rows query will return first row quickly. The query can be performed for a long time only if Default_Email_Creds is not a table. This can take place in case Default_Email_Creds is a View with a complex filter.

At second, you code is very inefficient and do five SQL queries to server. I advise to do in a such way:

```
    var res = (from c in ctx.Default_Email_Creds select new {c.Hostname, c.UserName, c.Password, c.Mail_From}).FirstOrDefault();
    if(res != null)
    {
        serverHostname = res.Hostname;
        serverUsername  = res.UserName;
        serverPassword  = res.Password;
        mailFrom  = res.Mail_From;
    }
```

Comment: The only thing that doesn't seem to make sense to me though is that the connection strings are the same whether it succeeds in communicating with the database or not. As I said in a comment on my question, the program can talk to the database using the same strings, but then the only time the connection string doesn't work is when it tries to perform the code I posted.

Comment: OK. If connection string work in other cases, I advise to use the code that i wrote in the answer.
`Enumarable.Any(...)` load ALL rows from Default_Email_Creds table (SQL query `SELECT * FROM Default_Email_Creds`) and after check is it any rows. If  Default_Email_Creds have many rows it may lead to connection timeout.